# WP7: Will app link in marketplace changed when hidden app will become public?

Tags: windows-phone-7

If I publish app as hidden and then make it public, will it's link changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Zune URL is based on the application ID, so as long as it is the same (you didn't change it), the URL will follow this structure:

> http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=APP_ID

Comment: For the record, the structure is this today: **http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=APP_ID** (Been a while since you last submitted a App Dennis?)